# How to access parent query values to construct a new query?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

In [graphql](/questions/tagged/graphql) I'd like construct `venues` query using the `coordiantes` provided to the parent `movies` query, while in `events` I'd like to use parent venue ID, e.g.

```
{
  movies(coordinates: {latitude: 51.509865, longitude: -0.118092}) {
    id,
    venues (coordinates: [parent query coordinates]) {
      id,
      events (coordinates: [parent query coordinates], venueId: [parent query venue]) {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to reference parent query parameters/ result?

Comment: Hi @Gajus, did my answer resolve your question? :)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you are trying to achieve (reusing arguments) can be done using [GraphQL variables](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables). The second thing however (reusing output values as inputs) cannot be achieved, to the best of my knowledge.
Both however sound like your type relationship is not correctly defined. Let's see each of these points in more details.

#### Reusing arguments using variables

***TL;DR*** Variables are a key concept to reuse arguments but might not be ideal in the situation described by the OP. See second part of this answer below. I am leaving it here to give full details.

[GraphQL variables](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) are very appropriate to define arguments once and use them multiple times.

A minimal example using [`swapi-graphql`](https://github.com/graphql/swapi-graphql) would look like this:

```
query SomePeopleAndCompatriots($numberOfResults: Int) {
  allPeople(first: $numberOfResults) {
    name
    homeworld {
      name
      residents(first: $numberOfResults) {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

while declaring the following variable:

```
{ "numberOfResults": 3 }
```

In practice, this API implements the [notions of node and edges](http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/#pagination-and-edges) so the actual query is a bit more complicated, but feel free to [play with it](http://graphql.org/swapi-graphql/?query=query(%24numberOfResults%3A%20Int)%20%7B%0A%20%20allPeople(first%3A%20%24numberOfResults)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20homeworld%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20residentConnection(first%3A%20%24numberOfResults)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&operationName=undefined&variables=%7B%0A%20%20%22numberOfResults%22%3A%203%0A%7D).

[This reference](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/) will give you a bit more details on how to use arguments using GraphQL.js but since you did not provide code corresponding to your schema declaration, you will need to tweak the details.

In your case, it seems to me that you already defined `coordinates` as an input type. Let's assume you called if `CoordinatesInput`, your query would now look like (omitting `venueId` on purpose, see rest of this answer below):

```
query MoviesAndVenuesAndEvents($coordinates: CoordinatesInput) {
  movies(coordinates: $coordinates) {
    id
    venues (coordinates: $coordinates) {
      id
      events (coordinates: $coordinates) {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

passing the corresponding variable:

```
{ "coordinates": { "latitude": 51.509865, "longitude": -0.118092 } }
```

This would do what you expect, but this might not be the best route, as we will see below.

#### Improving your type relations

Using the information I have, your query, it looks like the types behind `movies`, `venues` and `events` have no knowledge of each other. This means your schema cannot make use of all of GraphQL's power. Think of your schema as a tree, where `events` is a child of `venue`, and `venues` is a child of `movies`.

In the case of `venueId`, you should not even need it.
Let's make some assumption on your schema declaration. Your `VenueType` would look like this:

```
const VenueType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Venue'
  id: /* ... */,
  // ...
  events: {
    type: new GraphQLList(EventType),
    description: 'All events happening at this venue',
    resolve: venue => venue.getEvents()
  )
});
```

When you query `events` on all results from `venues`, you actually request the resolver to call `getEvents()` on a given `venue`, that you can manipulate. I don't know your implementation, but it could simply do `venue.events`, or `Event.findAllByVenue(venue.id)`, etc. This is where you make sure only the events for that specific venue are retrieved, and not all events in your storage.

[This example](https://github.com/steveluscher/zero-to-graphql/blob/master/zero-node/schema.js#L35-L71) will provide you with more details on how to do this.

Similarly, `MovieType` should have `venues` that resolves to `movie => movie.getVenues()`, which is why the first part of my answer is not ideal to your situation. In the end, your query should look like:

```
query MoviesAndVenuesAndEvents($coordinates: CoordinatesInput) {
  movies(coordinates: $coordinates) {
    id
    venues {
      id
      events {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which essentially says: "Fetch me all movies given these coordinates, and for each movie give me all venues and all events for these venues".

If what you are trying to get is all the movies being played in a given area (only focusing on movies and venues for now, but you can extrapolate this to events), then your query should probably be:

```
venues(coordinates: $coordinates) {
  id
  movies
}
```

but this last example would likely gives you duplicates that you have to flatten on the client. To focus on movies first, you would use the previous example, making sure your `movies` resolver only retrieves movies for the passed coordinates. Again making complete assumptions on your backend, it might look like this:

```
resolve: coordinates => allMovies.filter(movie =>
  movie.venues.some(venue => venue.coordinates === coordinates)
)
```